# Pose on global_costmap

Tags: ros, navigation, global-costmap, local-costmap

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I set the parameters /move_base/global_costmap/origin_x and /move_base/global_costmap/origin_y -50.0 and -50.0 (width is 100.0), becouse the robot was in angle of global map (parameters were 0.0 and 0.0). But it still have been in [angle](http://hkar.ru/Ct1D) (the static map from map_server is on picture).
In local costmap the parameters are same. And the robot is in the centre of it.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/213850/pose-on-global_costmap/) by [flaminga](https://answers.ros.org/users/22598/flaminga/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5 on 2015-07-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Try visualizing in the map frame?

---

Originally posted by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) with karma: 10932 on 2015-07-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [flaminga](https://answers.ros.org/users/22598/flaminga/) on 2015-07-16**:
It is near with odom and base_link frame. There isn't any coordinate system in the centre of offset static map

**Comment by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on 2015-07-16**:
What I'm saying is that it is displaying in its default pose since the global frame in rviz is not /map. If you change the global frame to map, does it change where the map is displayed?